# Is it possible to transfer an Ultimate Team from Fifa 13 to Fifa 15?

Tags: fifa-15

I started the Ultimate Team mode in Fifa 15 on PS4 and it automatically created a new team with a club name I couldn't choose, although I already had an Ultimate Team on the same Origin ID in Fifa 13 on PS3.

Is it not possible to keep the team name and status (the new one now says established in June 15), or would I have had to do something to get it carried over to the new game?

I didn't play Fifa 14, would that have been necessary to carry it over? It did carry over my Fifa level and points.